# hola, necesito ayuda, soy nuevo en laravel y me gustaria saber el como modificar un solo atributo de una tala

Tags: php, laravel

```
//Esto son los atributos, practicamente quiero tratar de utilizar esta forma
//solicitudes::find($id);    

public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('solicitudes', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id')->unique();
                $table->string('titulo',10);
                $table->string('mensaje',1000);
                $table->boolean('estado')->default(false);
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Comment: bienvenido a SO en español para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, te invito a leer [ask]

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta puedes utilizar tranquilamente `solicitudes::find($id); ` como indicas con esa estructura. El `->unique()` en increments no es necesario ponerlo. ¿Qué versión de laravel estas utilizando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para modificar un atributo de una tabla, debes hacer lo siguiente:

Buscar el registro que quieres modificar:

```
$miSolicitud = Solicitudes::find($id);
```

Luego, modificas los atributos de la siguiente forma:

```
$miSolicitud->atributoUno = "Valor de atributo"
```

Cambiando "atributoUno" por el nombre de la columna que quieres modificar.

Por último, para guardar escribes:

```
$miSolicitud->save();
```

Lo anterior debes hacerlo (por lo general) en las clases Controladoras (App\Controllers). El código que pusiste en la pregunta, es una migración, la cual sirve para crear tablas en la base de datos. Revisa qué son los verbos o métodos HTTP y la documentación de [controladores en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers) para que manejes adecuadamente los métodos que se usan para transacciones de bases de datos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, me sirvio muchisimo, me salvaste la vida